# Elasticsearch find uniqueness of content

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a system that pulls in articles and stores them in an elasticsearch index. When a new article is available I want to determine how unique the article's content is before I publish it on my site, so that I can try and reduce duplicates.

Currently I search for the new article title against the index using a `min_score` filter and if there are 0 results then it can be published:

```
{
    "index": "articles",
    "type": "article",
    "body": {
        "min_score": 1,
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "[ARTICLE TITLE HERE]",
                "type": "best_fields",
                "fields": [
                    "title^3",
                    "description"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not very accurate as you can imagine, most articles get published with a fair amount of duplicates.

How do you think I could improve this (if at all)?

Comment: Have you seen [More Like This Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html)? Looks like a exact use case.

Comment: [this question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/plagiarism-detection/31906) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Well , you need to handle this before indexing the document. 
My best solution would be to model the _id based on title , so that if the same title exist , the new document can be discarded ( using _create API ) or all document can be discarded. 
Even better , you can use upsert so that the exisitng document is updated by the duplicate info , like you can tell that news from this source has also appeared in this source.
You can see some practical example of the same [here](https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch).